# Set JFrame's resizing to try to put a selected component on the screen

Tags: java, swing

I need my JFrame to focus a component when I resize it. It currently displays the top left corner space, and I need it to display the bottom left one.

Screens:

Default (when it's first openned): http://prntscr.com/8zv0ua

How the resizing looks: http://prntscr.com/8zv17e

I want the components "Challenge 1 title", "Challenge #2 and Challenge #2 description" and "Challenge #3 and Challenge #3 description" to be on the screen when the user resizes it to that size.

How can I set the main component, or object to focus when the window is resized?

Comment: Put your components into JPanels, and decide for yourself which JPanels should be displayed at what times.

Comment: And how do I make the bottom left JPanel to be the focused one?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, but there's a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) where the JPanel you want to focus on is the one and only JPanel displayed.

Comment: I want resizing to prioritize a certain part of the screen, not the top left one